# What are these place names (in present-day Slovakia) from this US passenger list in 1913?

Tags: manifest, place-names, hungary, czechoslovakia

The full passenger list can be found below -- I'm looking at the entry for "Ignatz Schwarz" line 14.

What is the name of the city he identified as last place of residence (also same thing as the city for wife in origin country)?

What is the name of the city he identified as his birthplace?

I believe both places are somewhere in present-day Slovakia (Kosice or Presov area) and the name of the places are likely the Hungarian names for them.

[image: City of last residence and name and address of relation in origin country]
[image: Birthplace]
[image: Passenger Manifest - page 1]
[image: Passenger Manifest - page 2]

Comment: The "SI" next to his record indicates he was detained and brought to a Board of Special Inquiry. There should be 2 more pages with information about him in the ship's manifest, one the list of detained aliens, and the other the page for the board of special inquiry. Have you found those pages? Perhaps they will have useful information.

Also, have you identified the relative he was going to? It seems to be "brother i[n] l[aw] <something> Engel" in "New York NY". He might have been from the same town. This is probably a case where it will be easy to read once you know what you're looking at.

Comment: Also, the town of last permanent residence seems to be some capital letter then a period then a space then a word. I’ve seen place names in (former parts of) Hungary where the name is a compound word, and sometimes it’s written with the first part of the compound word abbreviated. I know I’ve seen that done with town names where the first part is “Nagy” meaning “big” or “large”, which is the beginning of a number of Hungarian town names.

Comment: @aem This is all very helpful, thank you!

Comment: Ancestry has the page where he was detained. It's typed, so easier to read, but there's less information on it.

Comment: This will be helpful: http://www.iabsi.com/gen/public/kingdom_of_hungary.htm " Given that the majority of emigrants from these lands came during a very short period of time, 1889-1914, you may need a moment to understand the historical and political context of the times.  This is important, since the village names immigrants gave on ship manifests, on census documents as well as records before 1918 are organized according to their Hungarian names, with some exception."  Also, as it appears that your ancestor was listed as "Hebr" you probably need to be looking at JewishGen resources as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a guess, but I'm bold and adding this as answer rather than a comment. I think it is **Kysak (Hungarian: Sároskőszeg)** half-way between Prešov and Košice.

Rationale:
The first writer had a tendency to move letters that near together so that they might appear as one. You see this for example with "Austria" on line 10 where s and t nearly are one. In the same way the first letter of the town is a "S." (first I thought it might be "St."), then the next letter is a "K" (quite apparent at least to me) and then we have again a letter that near that it nearly vanishes. It is a "o" and the accent is shifted to the right. That is also why the "s" is cut off. Then I think a "e" follows and the last one is clearly a "k" again.

That makes "S. Kösek" where the writer might have misheard "kőszeg". On the other page we have a different handwriting and there I read "Kosz." So this writer heard better. Not sure why the accent got missing though (ő [note the acute accent] is pronounced longer so no chance to mishear that for an o). Maybe we see it in the sloppy connecting line between the "o" and the "s".